# passing multiple values to use anchorscroll

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
<div class="slideHeading" id="slide-{{$index}}" ng-click="scrollTo('slide-'index)">
```

Probably a really easy question but how can I pass through slide-{{$index}} for the parameter scrollTo? It works fine if it's set to id='{{$index}}' and scrollTo(index) but i want to add the slide- to it as well

```
scope.widget.scrollTo = function(id) {
$location.hash(id);
$anchorScroll();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use string concatenation in your `ng-click`

```
ng-click="scrollTo('slide-' + $index)"
```